# How do I move an expensive simulation to an asynchronous task?

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity` which consists of a `ViewPager` and an `ActionBar`. This `ViewPager` has an adapter with 3 fragments. These fragments change the values of their `TextView` depending on which item is selected in the `ActionBar`.

Here's my problem: Whenever I swipe between views in the `ViewPager`, I wish to set the data of the fragment based on the item selected in the `ActionBar`. I attempt this by setting up a listener as such :

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) 
        {
            setTimePeriod(actionBarItemPosition);
        }
    }
```

Then, `setTimePeriod()` calls two simulation methods: `getComparedUsage()` and `getThisUsage()`.  Each of these are heavy on the CPU load and as as a result my **UI is extremely laggy** when swiping between views.

How do I solve this?

```
private void setTimePeriod(int position)
{
    periodDropDownPosition = position;

    // Get a reference to the active fragment currently shown by the ViewPager.
    currentFragment = (DetailedFragment) mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    List<UsageEntry> dataSet = currentFragment.getDataSet();

    setViewReferencessOnActiveFragment(currentFragment);

    differenceTextView = (TextView) activeView.findViewById(R.id.usage_results_total_value_tv);
    try
    {
        switch(position)
        {
        case PERIOD_DAY:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_day);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_day);  
            comparedUsage = getComparedUsage(PERIOD_DAY, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            thisUsage = getThisUsage(PERIOD_DAY, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            break;
        case PERIOD_WEEK:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_week);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_week);         
            comparedUsage = getComparedUsage(PERIOD_WEEK, dataSet);
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            thisUsage = getThisUsage(PERIOD_WEEK, dataSet);
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            break;
        case PERIOD_MONTH:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_month);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_month);
            comparedUsage = getComparedUsage(PERIOD_MONTH, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            thisUsage = getThisUsage(PERIOD_MONTH, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            break;
        case PERIOD_YEAR:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_year);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_year);
            comparedUsage = getComparedUsage(PERIOD_YEAR, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            thisUsage = getThisUsage(PERIOD_YEAR, dataSet); 
                        // This call brings the phone to its knees
            break;
        }

        setCashOrUnits(isInCashMode);

    }catch(NotEnoughDataException e)
    {
        noDataLayout = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_not_enough_data_view);
        noDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resultsView = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_view);
        resultsView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        noDataLayout = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_not_enough_data_view);
        noDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resultsView = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_view);
        resultsView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which two methods are CPU intensive?  `setViewReferencessOnActiveFragment()` and `setCashOrUnits()`?

Comment: getComparedUsage and getThisUsage. It says so right in the code segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this.

The `AsyncTask` will allow you to run the slow operations in the background (another thread), and then execute some UI code when it's finished, to update your display.  While the slow operations are running, your device will not appear to be completely unresponsive.

An `AsyncTask` subclass (would be an *inner* class in the class you show us above):

```
private class UsageTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

     private List<UsageEntry> dataSet;

     public UsageTask(List<UsageEntry> data) {
         this.dataSet = data;
     }

     protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
         Boolean success = Boolean.TRUE;
         int period = params[0];
         try {
             // I'm assuming these two methods can throw the exceptions?
             comparedUsage = getComparedUsage(period, dataSet); 
             thisUsage = getThisUsage(period, dataSet);
         } catch(NotEnoughDataException e) {
             success = Boolean.FALSE; 
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch(NullPointerException e) {
             success = Boolean.FALSE; 
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
         return success;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
         if (success) {
            // I'm assuming this call somehow modifies the UI?
            setCashOrUnits(isInCashMode);
         } else {
            noDataLayout = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_not_enough_data_view);
            noDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultsView = (RelativeLayout)activeView.findViewById(R.id.results_view);
            resultsView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }
     }
 }
```

and then use it like this:

```
private void setTimePeriod(int position)
{
    periodDropDownPosition = position;

    // Get a reference to the active fragment currently shown by the ViewPager.
    currentFragment = (DetailedFragment) mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    List<UsageEntry> dataSet = currentFragment.getDataSet();

    setViewReferencessOnActiveFragment(currentFragment);

    differenceTextView = (TextView) activeView.findViewById(R.id.usage_results_total_value_tv);

    switch(position)
    {
        case PERIOD_DAY:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_day);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_day);
            break;  
        case PERIOD_WEEK:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_week);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_week);         
            break;
        case PERIOD_MONTH:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_month);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_month);
            break;
        case PERIOD_YEAR:
            resultsThisTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_this_year);
            resultsComparedToTextView.setText(R.string.compared_to_text_compared_year);
            break;
        default: 
            return;
            break;
    }

    UsageTask task = new UsageTask(dataSet);
    task.execute(position);
}
```

Note: I don't know exactly what the UI looks like when you set the text in your text views, as shown in the `switch-case` statement above.  It's possible that you don't want to change those until **after** the slow operations complete.  If so, just move them to `onPostExecute()`.

Also, it's probably good practice to show some kind of progress indicator before the slow operation starts, to let the user know what's happening.  You could do that right before creating the task, in `setTimePeriod()`, or implement [onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) in the `UsageTask` class, and put it there.  Stop the progress indicator in `onPostExecute()`.